# SWFUpload gives the error "Invalid function name: ReturnUploadStart" in Firefox only

Tags: firefox, swfupload

I'm using SWFUpload to upload files on my website. It works fine in all browsers except Firefox, where it always gives the javascript error `Invalid function name: ReturnUploadStart` as soon as the upload starts.

I'm using SWFUpload 2.2.0 Beta 2 with jquery-asyncUpload-0.1.js. I'm using Firefox 6.0.2

What gives?

Comment: Did you ever find out what this was?  It currently has me stumped....

Comment: Sorry, no. My answer below was as far as I got.

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs in Firefox if there is no css to style the progress bar. Other browsers seem to work just fine, showing the text "Uploading..." instead, but for some reason Firefox breaks.

Try using this css to get you started:

```
DIV.ProgressBar { width: 100px; padding: 0; border: 1px solid black; margin-right: 1em; height:.75em; margin-left:1em; display:-moz-inline-stack; display:inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; }
DIV.ProgressBar DIV { background-color: Green; font-size: 1pt; height:100%; float:left; }
SPAN.asyncUploader OBJECT { position: relative; top: 5px; left: 10px; }
```

Comment: Hmm... not sure this is the whole story: sometimes it just stops working again. Definitely something to do with the css though - an unrelated change in the css can cause the error to reoccur.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- included the CSS as in [teedyay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7363138/614523)
- upgrade swfupload to latest stable (2.2.0 at time of writing)
- only manipulated the flash video (upload button) in the `upload completed` event (using a jquery `hide()`)